# LibGdx Stage/Actor InputListener (Appropriate Area for InputListener)

Tags: libgdx

I have a class Bubble that extends Actor.

```
public Bubble(MyGdxGame game,Texture texture){
    this.game=game;
    setPosition(0,0);
    setSize(32,32);

    gameObject=new GameObject("","bubble");
    direction=new MovementDirection();
    sprite=new Sprite(texture);

    setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
    setWidth(sprite.getWidth());
    setHeight(sprite.getHeight());
    setBounds(0,0,sprite.getWidth(),sprite.getHeight());

    addListener(new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            Gdx.app.log("BUBBLE", "touchdown");
            return true;  // must return true for touchUp event to occur
        }
        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            Gdx.app.log("BUBBLE", "touchup");
        }
    });
}
```

This is in a class that implements Screen

```
public void show() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.show();

    //2 bubbles test
    gameStage=new Stage(MyGdxGame.WIDTH,MyGdxGame.HEIGHT,true);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(gameStage);

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        Bubble b=new Bubble(game,Assets.bubbleTexture);
        b.randomize();
        gameStage.addActor(b);
    }

    //if (bubbleList==null)
    //  createBubbles();

}
```

Am I going about this the wrong way by adding the listener @ the bubble level?  (It seems creating an InputListener for every bubble I spawn is a little crazy).

According to : http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html 
Actor has a touchUp() and touchDown event - but complains when i try to override them (which lead me to believe they dont exist). Overriding these I feel would be a better approach

Comment: What version of libgdx are you using here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs you linked to are outdated.
Those methods were deprecated and removed in favor of using `InputListener`s.

In your example if you want to use the same `InputListener` instance for all instances of your `Actor` class (`Bubble`) then you can just implement the `InputListener` to refer to the Actor class instance using [inputEvent.getRelatedActor()](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/InputEvent.html#getRelatedActor--) and then instantiate one such `InputListener` as a static member of `Bubble` and pass it in the constructor to `addListener`.

```
class Bubble extends Actor{
   private static InputListener bubbleListener= new InputListener() {
      public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)        {
         Bubble b = (Bubble) event.getRelatedActor();
         b.doSomething();
         ...
         return true; //or false
      }
   }
   public Bubble(){
       addListener(bubbleListener);
       ...
   }
   ...

}
```

Comment: Is that the proper place to put it? Or should i do it at the stage level? Im wondering what is best practice or recommended.